# Triple Chainset

Tags: shimano, gears, chainring, 7-speed

Trying to replace my 52/42/32 front 21 speed chainset with same. The outer chain ring 104bcd 52t would also be OK. Unable to find.  This is for an English trike.

[image: original Shimano]

Comment: I Googled `outer chain ring 104bcd 52t` and found a number of options.

Comment: 104 is MTB/Compact so 52 is a big ring for it. Might be better off replacing the crankset with a standard road triple, 52/42/30 is common.

Comment: I did the Google search too, and the first hits seem to be pages that list both 52t and 104bcd rings, but not a ring that has both. Specialites TA has rings up to 50t, and I don't know about other manufacturers that have even that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Custom ring chainset is available here

https://www.spacycles.co.uk/m8b17s109p2004/SPA-CYCLES-TD-2-Touring-Triple-Chainset-with-custom-TA-chainrings

Comment: Try to avoid linking to a reseller.  OP is likely not in the UK, even though they've mentionsed an "english trike".   A Manufacturer's website would be better, and OP can work to find it somewhere useful for them.  //  I see they are the manufacturer and seller as well, so fair enough.

Comment: Spa are good - they built me a wheel (that I later destroyed in a crash), but they only ship within the UK & Ireland at the moment